# queue and scheduling to run functions in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

I have multiple functions in a python script. Each of these functions can be run in 2 to 60 seconds. I want to run all these functions every minute. So, each function should be run every minute.
I use the schedule library in python. But the problem is sometimes it takes more than 60s to run all functions. So, the schedule library misses some functions during the ruuing.

are there any ways that I can create a queue and make sure that all backlog functions will be executed?

Comment: Can you share your code? And what schedule library are you using? And also, if the functions are taking more than 60 seconds to load, you might want to increase the interval between the functions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.